# Bit conversion operations in PHP

Tags: php, casting, bit-manipulation

I find myself in need of performing bit-level conversion on variables in PHP. In more detail, I have a bit stream that is read as an integer by hardware, and I need to do some operations on the bits to make it into what its actually supposed to be (a float). I have to do this a few times for different formats, and the functionality I need is

- Being able to select and move individual bits in a variable
- Being able to cast statically one type of variable to the other (ie. int to float)

I know php natively supports bitwise AND, OR, etc, and shift operations, but I was wondering if:

- there may already be a library in php that does this sort of thing
- I would be better off with delegating the calculations to some other language

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it [pack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [unpack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) that you want?

Answer (score 0):

For converting bit stream to whatever you need use [**unpack()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php).

Once converted to integer, you can use [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). Note, that they don't support floats, so in case of float it'd first be casted to integer.

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php